# Mapping values based on 'from' and 'to' columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe example below.

```
From|to
01|03
05|09
03|02
02|06
```

The final_value should be updated with the latest data i.e., 01 is changed to 03 later 03 is changed to 02 and so on 02 is changed to 06. So 01 should be replaced with latest value 06 and 03 should be be replaced with latest value 06 and so on

I need to map these like below based on 'from' and 'to' columns. Please let me know how i can make use of operations on dataframe?

```
From|to|final_value
01|03|06
05|09|09
03|02|06
02|06|06
```

Comment: Your desired result seems simplistic, for instance you could just do `df['final_value'] = '05'`

Comment: I need to map it 01->02->03->04->05 So if i append new value 05->06 the final_value column should be updated to 06

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense to me, edit your question and explain clearly the logic rather than just dumping the desired result.

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: Will you ever have a case where the numbers overlap. I.e. what would the result be if the second line was 05 03

Comment: The numbers will not overlap

Answer (score 0):

Where your dataframe is df:
I have assumed that all the values in the dataframe are strings, i.e. that is 01 is really `"01"`

```
df
Out[]: 
  From  To
0   01  02
1   02  03
2   03  04
3   04  05

# Make a copy of the df dataframe
res = df.copy()
# Set the 'final value' column to be equal to the maximum numerical value of the df dataframe
res['final_value'] = df.values.astype(int).max()

res
Out[]:
  From  To  final_value
0   01  02            5
1   02  03            5
2   03  04            5
3   04  05            5
```

Now whenever `df` is updated, if you run:

```
res = df.copy()
res['final_value'] = df.values.astype(int).max()
```

Then the result dataframe `res` will also be updated

Comment: Sorry for the wrong example. It is not to find the maximum value. it is to find the final mapping value.like below
 From  To
  01  03
  05  09
  03  02
  02  06                                                                                                              
Out:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              From  To Final
  01  03  06
  05  09  09
  03  02  06
  02  06  06